# Entity Framework - Parameter Not Supplied?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am executing a NonQuery against a SQL stored procedure using Entity Framework.

The property it is complaining about is indeed null for this record, however my stored procedure defines this as a nullable parameter.

Why is it complaining about this?

[image: Error]

SQL Proc definition:

[image: SQL Stored Procedure]

Comment: I can't see the screenshots, but you typically use `DBNull.Value` instead of `null` when setting parameter values.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks.  I created an object, if it's null set the object to DbNull.Value otherwise set it to the property value.

Answer (score 0):

D Stanley has the correct answer in the comments.

You can't pass null to the `SqlParameter`, you need to pass `DbNull.Value`.

So:

```
object comments = detail.ReferralComments;

if (comments == null) {
    comments = DBNull.Value;
} else {
    comments = detail.ReferralComments;
}

db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC dbo.Dual_SaveReferral @quoteGuid, @referralTypeID, @comments",
    new SqlParameter("@quoteGuid", detail.QuoteGuid),
    new SqlParameter("@referralTypeID", detail.ReferralTypeID),
    new SqlParameter("@comments", comments));
}
```